# How to select columns in RStudio Viewer?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a `dataframe` and would like to inspect and compare several columns. How can I select two or more columns with the data Viewer? I do not want to create a subsample for those columns each time. Is there another way?

```
data(mtcars)
View(mtcars$mpg)
View(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$mpg) # not working
View(c(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)) # shows 2 columns underneath each other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View()` will only take a dataframe, not 2 seperate vectors

With base R you could do something like

```
View(mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl")])
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually use this code to do this

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars%>%
  select(mpg,cyl)%>%
  View
```

It uses the `dplyr` package and the pipe `%>%`. It works in a way that you first give it your data, then you manipulate it (in your case just selecting the rows) and then throw in `View,` `head()`, `str()` or any other function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.frame` instead of `c` in the `View`, i.e.

```
View(data.frame(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl))
```